# Ubuntu 14.04 - vlc starts extremely slow

Tags: vlc

I have a big issue with VLC player.. I love this player I do not want to use any other - but !!

when I try to open a movie I have to wait about 10-30 sec before it starts. It is extremely annoying when I always HAVE TO wait...

Do you know what could caused this delay?

Comment: no one knows how to solve it?

Comment: just to update ... I switched to smplayer  :( bye bye vlc

Answer (score -1):

Tried several solutions found in forums but none really worked for me. but most of them affirmed its effectivity. You can try these if you want:

1. Tools > Show settings: ALL > Input / Codecs > Access modules > File > Subdirectory behavior > NONE
2. Tools > Show settings: ALL > Playlist > UNCHECK: Use media library
3. Uninstall Microsoft Silverlight

You can try one by one see which one works. None really worked for me EXCEPT - Installing an OLDER version - Like 2.0.5. It now only takes a second to pull up. :)

Hope this helps!